# How to get a dot(or a very small circle) to center at the middle of a JFrame?

Tags: java

I am trying to get a dot to stay at the center of the screen regardless of however the user move the screen around, or resize the screen using paint Graphics or Graphics2d.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try rendering it using `canvas.getHeight() / 2` and `canvas.getWidth() / 2`?

Comment: What are you drawing the dot on? Whatever it is, get the width and height of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    int x = getWidth() /2 ;
    int y = getHeight() / 2;
    g.drawOval(x, y, 10, 10);
}
```

To make sure it stays in the middle all the time, add a componentlistener to your JFrame, like this:

```
MyJframe() {
        addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
                repaint();
            }

        });
}
```

*The componentlistener is not needed....*